# Subscript with fraction, large vertical spacing

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

In a paragraph, the expression $A_{b/c}^{dd}$ causes an undesired larger vertical spacing of the sentence where it appears (compared to the rest of the paragraph). 
I have tested some solutions (eg. /*tensor, /subdepth packages) from similar problems to no avail.
Is there a way to handle this properly?

Comment: It is being handled correctly! :) You can always `\smash{..}` it, but then you may have descenders/ascenders sticking into it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It doesn't happen with the Computer Modern fonts, but I can see it with `mathptmx`. Can you please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? The problem with `mathptmx` seems to be in a too big slash.

Comment: You may need `smash` even more in case you have:

`... some text $\smash{A_{\frac{b}{c}}^{dd}}$ more text ...`

check this out...

Answer (score 2):

You can make TeX ignore the height of a formula with the `\smash` command.  Try

```
... some text $\smash{A_{b/c}^{dd}}$ more text ...
```

The `\smash` macro is provided by plain TeX and it sets the height and depth of a maths subformula to zero.  Beware that this might make your subscripts and superscripts overprint the lines above or below.

Comment: Tested and approved. \smash works as needed. Thanks guys.